# Discriminant of $\mathrm{Tr}(xy)$ is $p^2$ in a maximal order of discriminant p in a quaternion algebra

Tags: number-theory

I am trying to prove that $\mathrm{Tr}(xy)$ has discriminant $p^2$ in a maximal order of discriminant $p$ in a quaternion algebra.  Does anybody have any hints to get a handle on this?

Comment: What is your definition of the discriminant of an order?